# What is the maximum number of non-zero entries of a matrix $A$ with non-negative entries that fulfills $A^2 = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory

A question I found and that I could not answer so far. Assuming that $A$ is a $n \times n$ matrix with non-negative entries, that fulfills the equation $A^2= 0$, where $0$ is the zero matrix. What is the maximal number of positive entries for $A$?

So far I have tried going through the specific entries, namely to solve $0 = \sum_{k=1}^n a_{i,k} \cdot a_{k,j}$ for all $i,j$, but I was hoping for a simpler way. An example for $n=5$ has been

$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$

which fulfills the equation, but I do not know if there are better possibilities

Comment: What did you try so far? Please tell us in the post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Consider the incidence graph of the matrix obtained by replacing every non-zero entry by 1. A path of length 2 in this graph corresponds to the product of two non-zero coefficients, say $a_{i,j}a_{j,k}$.  In your example, the graph would have 5 vertices and edges $(2,1), (3,1), (4,1), (2,5), (3,5), (4,5)$.
Thus the problem can be reduced to the following graph-theoretic question:

**Question**. What is the maximum number of edges of a directed graph containing no paths of length 2?

This question was discussed in [1, Theorem 4.3] or [2, Theorem 1] and the answer is $k^2$ if $n = 2k$ and $k^2 + k$ if $n = 2k + 1$. For your case, $n = 5$, $k = 2$ and $k^2 + k = 6$, in agreement with your bound.

[1] Bermond, J.-C.; Sotteau, D.; Germa, A.; Heydemann, [M.-C. Chemins et circuits dans les graphes orientés](https://inria.hal.science/hal-02379949/file/BGHS80b-circuits.pdf). (French) *Ann. Discrete Math.* **8** (1980), 293--309

[2] Sotteau, D.; Wojda, A. P., Digraphs without directed path of length two or three. *Discrete Math.* **58** (1986), no. 1, 105--108.

Comment: I think you meant “the maximum number of *arcs*”?

Comment: oops! Thanks for pointing out this error. Edited.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's an approach I hadn't thought about